# Display the value of selected menu item on a button angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck at this issue i have a list of menu item

```
<md-menu-item ng-value="menuItem.value" ng-repeat="menuItem in filtermenu.menuItems" ng-click="activeFilterCtrl.selectedfilter(menuItem)" translate>
    <md-button>
        {{ menuItem.name }}
    </md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

Following is the code i want to display the value of selected menu item on a button or on a label which should be displayed after selection of menu item.
Please help me resolve the issue

Comment: No there is one more component on the page such as <div  flex>
  <md-button ></md-button>
</div>

Comment: I would set a variable in your controller function, then use that variable as a label on the button

Comment: How to use that variable on a button could you please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you call the selectedFilter(menuItem) function. You can then add this in your function:

```
$scope.selectedFilter = function(menuItem){
// your code here
$scope.myLabel = menuItem.name;
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<md-button>
    {{myLabel}}
</md-button>
```

Comment: i have one more question i am using state provider and i am reloading the state could you please also tell how to save the value of the button even after reloading it     $state.go('abc', params,{reload: true});

Comment: you can pass the value of that label as a parameter:
`<a ui-sref="adcPage({myLabel: myLabel})">link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `md-button` directive creates its own scope and therefore `menuItem` is not present at this scope. Try `$parent.menuItem` to access the parent scope which should be the scope of `ng-repeat`.